# Difficulty with servo control using TI MSP430

Tags: servo, msp430

I'm using an MSP430FR4133 chip to test out a servo (I haven't used or interfaced with servos before). I believe I've attached the servo wires to the correct pins, but when I run the program to turn it 90 degrees and then back to 0, all I hear is clicking inside of the servo. Here's my code and the pin diagram:

[image: Here's the pin diagram]

The servos operate on 5-6V so I connected the servo ground wire to GND (Pin 1), the servo power wire to 5V (Pin 1) and the servo control wire to PWM (Pin 19).

And here's my code:

```
#include <Servo.h>

Servo servo;

int pos = 0;
const int buttonPin = PUSH2;

void setup() {
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  servo.attach(11);
}

void loop() {

  int buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    servo.write(90);
  }
}
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: There could be many things wrong here, but one that immediately jumps out is that you generally should not draw power for a hobby servo or any other motor *through* an MCU board.  The MCU should provide signal; you need to provide dedicated paths for power, and of course have a common ground between signal and power.

Comment: What Chris said about the power supply.  I was half expecting you to say you told it to move and the processor locked up!  I'm not familiar with the code base you're using -- you may want to double-check the documentation and make sure that you call servo.write with an argument in degrees -- it could easily be an argument in tenths or 1/100ths of degrees.  If it **is** 1/100ths of degrees, then when you told the servo to move 90/100ths of a degree it may very well make a 'tick' but no apparent motion.

Comment: "but when I run the program to turn it [to] 90 degrees **and then back to 0**" - where does your code do that?

Comment: You mentioned that you have attached the control wire to 'pin 19'..but the code has 'servo.attach(11)'. Thats the thing I noticed as a arduino user. Try editing that as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library you're using but are you sure `90` is 90 degrees? A lot of libraries interpret `1500` as 0 degrees and `1000` as -90 degrees and `2000` as 90 degrees (or at least servo_min_travel and servo_max_travel which may be 45 degrees or 90 degrees or 180 degrees or any other value depending on servo)